# Jboss unable to start : some service stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs

Tags: jboss, windows-services, redhat

I am not able to start jBoss on windows server. when i hit jBoss start button in windows services then i am getting alert message as "Jboss unable to start : some service stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs"
Kindly help on this. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps configure JBoss EAP 6 as a Service in Microsoft Windows Server (Zip, Installer) as below:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html-single/Installation_Guide/index.html#Install_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_6_Microsoft_Windows_Service